# How can I remove a package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I have encounter a problem when I install a package, The error message:

```
$ dpkg -i 116667-Ubuntu\ xsplash\ clean\ theme.deb 
(Reading database ... 265031 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack 116667-Ubuntu xsplash clean theme.deb ...
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/share/images/ubuntu-default': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/images/xsplash': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing archive 116667-Ubuntu xsplash clean theme.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
rm: cannot remove '/usr/share/images/xsplash': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/share/images/xsplash': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/share/images/ubuntu-default': No such file or directory
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess new post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 116667-Ubuntu xsplash clean theme.deb

$ dpkg -l xsplash-clean message
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
iHR xsplash-clean  1.0          i386         (no description available)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -r xsplash-clean
```

dpkg man page explaining the `-r` option:

> **-r**, --remove, -P, --purge package...|-a|--pending Remove  an  installed  package. -r or --remove remove everything except conffiles.
>   This may avoid having to reconfigure the package  if  it  is 
>   reinstalled later.